# Rotate SCNNode then move relative to rotation?

Tags: swift, swift4, scenekit, scnnode

My node setup:

```
let node = SCNNode()
node.position = SCNVector3(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

I then wish to rotate the node by 90 degrees to the left which can be achieved with:

```
node.transform = SCNMatrix4Rotate(node.transform, .pi/2, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
```

Next, I want to translate the node forward one unit along the negative z axis relative to current rotation and end up with:

```
node.position = SCNVector3(-1.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

I have no idea how to get from the rotation of the node to the position of the node programmatically.

> Basically node begins at (0, 0, 0), its forward vector is the -z axis, node turns left and moves one unit forward to end up at (-1, 0, 0).

This isn't working:

```
func move(_ direction: moveDirection) {
    switch direction {
    case .forward: characterNode.position = SCNVector3(characterNode.position.x, characterNode.position.y, characterNode.position.z - 1.0)
    case .left: characterNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4Rotate(characterNode.pivot, -.pi/32, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    case .backward: characterNode.position = SCNVector3(characterNode.position.x, characterNode.position.y, characterNode.position.z + 1.0)
    case .right: characterNode.pivot = SCNMatrix4Rotate(characterNode.pivot, .pi/32, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming I have understood you correctly, once you have rotated your `SCNNode`, you want to move it forward it in that direction.

This can be done by using the `worldFront` value which is simply:

> The local unit -Z axis (0,0,-1) in world space.

As such this may be the answer you are looking for:

```
    //1. Create A Node Holder
    let nodeToAdd = SCNNode()

    //2. Create An SCNBox Geometry
    let nodeGeometry = SCNBox(width: 0.2, height: 0.2, length: 0.2, chamferRadius: 0)
    nodeGeometry.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = UIColor.cyan
    nodeGeometry.firstMaterial?.lightingModel = .constant
    nodeToAdd.geometry = nodeGeometry

    //3. Position It 1.5m Away From The Camera
    nodeToAdd.position = SCNVector3(0, 0, -1.5)

    //4. Rotate The Node By 90 Degrees On It's Y Axis
    nodeToAdd.rotation = SCNVector4Make(0, 1, 0, .pi / 2)

    //5. Add The Node To The ARSCNView
    augmentedRealityView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(nodeToAdd)

    //6. Use The World Front To Move The Node Forward e.g 

    /*
    nodeToAdd.simdPosition += nodeToAdd.simdWorldFront * 1.2
    */

    nodeToAdd.simdPosition += nodeToAdd.simdWorldFront

    //7. Print The Position
    print(nodeToAdd.position)

     /*
    SCNVector3(x: -0.999999881, y: 0.0, z: -1.50000024)
    */
```

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the last line or the value "1.2", could you explain? In my example I rotated (turned) left by using the y axis. Rotating +90 degrees on the x axis would have you facing the ceiling wouldn't it?

Comment: So you are rotating it on your YAxis? No worries I will updated. The 1.2 is just the distance we want to move it along the axis...

Comment: Updated with Debug example ^_________^ So obviously if you change the original Z value to 0, you will get the desired result I believe :)

Comment: Well this works, I don't really understand either of the simd properties though...

Comment: Is it possible to use the pivot property? Rotate the actual axis of the node and then translate through them?

Comment: Give it a shot and see ^______^

Comment: I've added to my original question. I can't get the node to move on the pivoted axis; it just sticks to the original.